# Unable to retrieve the state from the store after redirection in Redux React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am developing a Web application using React JS + Redux. I am new to React. What I am doing now is trying to set the state on one page and then retrieve the state in another page after redirection.

I have a Component called EventListComponent that displays the list of events. Inside that component, I change the state of a reducer calling an event.

This is the reducer function I call.

```
import * as EditEventActions from '../actions/edit.event.actions';

export default function (state = { }, action){
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case EditEventActions.EVENT_SET_EDITING_EVENT:
        return { ...state, event: action.payload }

        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

I fire the actions before redirecting to another page like this.

```
this.props.setEditingEvent(event);
    this.props.history.push({ 
       pathname : '/event/'+ event.id +'/edit'
    });
```

In the new page, I render the component called, EditEventComponent.

This is the definition of the EditEventComponent

```
export class EditEventComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        alert(this.props.event.id)//cannot retrieve event here
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <h4>This is the Edit Event component</h4>
        );
    }

}



function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        event: state.editEvent.event
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    return bindActionCreators({

    }, dispatch);
}


const enhance = compose(withWidth(), withStyles(themeStyles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps))
export default enhance(EditEventComponent);
```

As you can see, inside the EditEventComponent I am trying to retrieve the event field of the state which is set in the previous page. But I cannot retrieve it. 
My questions are

1. Is the state (of the redux store) reset after redirecting to the new page?
2. What is wrong with my code?
3. If what I am doing is not the right approach, what would be the best way to pass an object from one page to another in React Redux?

Here is my action

```
export const EVENT_SET_EDITING_EVENT = "(EVENT) SET EDITING EVENT";


export const setEditingEvent = (data) => ({
    type: EVENT_SET_EDITING_EVENT,
    payload: data
});
```

Here is the reducer

```
import * as EditEventActions from '../actions/edit.event.actions';

export default function (state = { }, action){
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case EditEventActions.EVENT_SET_EDITING_EVENT:
        return { ...state, event: action.payload }

        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

I expose the EventListComponent in this way as well.

```
const enhance = compose(withWidth(), withStyles(themeStyles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps))

export default enhance(EventListComponent);
```

Comment: I don't see `setEditingEvent` in `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: Hay, I mention in the question, I set it in the previos page before redirection.

Comment: Ah yes I see now, thanks. Might just be an issue of the route change before the store is updated? Can you log `this.props.event` in `componentDidUpdate()` of EditEventComponent and see if it is ever there?

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the way I am doing?

Comment: If the events are all in your store, you could use the `{id}` from your react-router params to get the event from the store

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not setting the type correctly in `setEditingEvent` action and the reducer returns the initial state since it doesn't hit `EVENT_SET_EDITING_EVENT`

Comment: Hi, I set it correctly. I just updated the question to show you my code for the reducer and actions.

Comment: @WaiYanHein try `this.props.dispatch(setEditingEvent(event));` and console.log(action.payload) inside the case.

Comment: @WaiYanHein  Do you connect the component to the redux store where you call the action?

Comment: I connect I guess. Please, check the last section. I have updated the question.